# Do you know whether employers can or will accept other evidence of eligibility to work, or is the residence card the only document they can consider?

Tags: united-kingdom

I hope you can guide me on this one. 
I was wondering if I can work as fast as possible in the UK just by showing I'm married to an EEA national. Basically, my question is the following: do you know whether employers can or will accept other evidence of eligibility to work, or is the residence card the only document they can consider?

I wonder if I can start working in the mean time as a baby sitter or waitress just by showing I am married to an EEA national. Can you guive me some guidance please? I really don't want to be out of work for a long time.

Comment: Given the fact that having a residence card is not mandatory for you and the way EU law is phrased I think they should be able to. I have no idea whether they will do it in practice (+1).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The magic search term you want is "right to work". You'll likely want the employers guides, rather than the employee ones, as that'll help you work out the options better.

For the full details, you can read the [Right to work checks: an employer's guide](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/right-to-work-checks-employers-guide) and [Acceptable right to work documents: an employer's guide](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/acceptable-right-to-work-documents-an-employers-guide). For a quick summary, there's the [Check a job applicant's 'right to work' documents](https://www.gov.uk/check-job-applicant-right-to-work) page.

You'll really need to read through those, and work out what (if any) of the things you have are the ones that Employers are legally protected from fines if they see + record. Based on [page 16 of the Acceptable right to work documents: an employer's guide](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/acceptable-right-to-work-documents-an-employers-guide), it looks like biometric residency cards are the normal way for non-EEA family members of EEA-citizens, but I haven't checked the list fully and I don't know what else you have!